Why not "what the wonderful piece of complex engineering their wings are..." but "how the wonderful piece..."?
How David Attenborough Captured Memorable Swan Moment 1:55

When you close up to a flying bird like this, you can see how the
wonderful piece of complex engineering their wings are, able to change
their shape and their beat to respond to every little change in the
currents of the air around them, and so propel them forward and lift
them upwards.

I have rarely encounterd this kind of usage. In "how exclamatory sentence", adjs/advs are always preceded, for example, "How beautiful the flowers are!"
So, is it because there are so many adjectives in the noun phrase that it is not inverted?-'wonderful, complex'

I would expect "what" there. And I'm not sure the word is actually "how". It's quite muffled. And note that this is David speaking off-the-cuff, not reading a script. If it is "how", I'd say he misspoke: he started to say something like "how the complex piece of engineering that their wings are fits together", but got turned around by the end of the sentence.

When you close up to a flying bird like this, you can see how the wonderful piece of complex engineering their wings are able to change their shape and their beat to respond to every little change in the currents of the air around them, and so propel them forward and lift them upwards.

I’m voting to close this question because the cited text is obviously syntactically invalid, so it can only be a "one-off" example

the text is syntactically correct, if you remove that comma. Only the phrase in bold is incorrect, and that is just because it is incomplete. The transcription is incorrect, not what he says.

@Michael Harvey How to understand "the wonderful piece of complex engineering"? Is it an appositive to "their wings"?

@Mr. Wang - precisely that, see my comment below my answer.

"what the wonderful piece of complex engineering their wings are" is wrong too. It should be "what a wonderful piece of complex engineering their wings are". But even Attenborough can't speak something clearly and correctly all the time.

@timchessish: You are mistaken. There's a significant difference in both the meaning and the syntax of You can see how wonderful [something] is compared to "exclamatory" How wonderful [something] is! And the cited text is neither - it's just "word salad".

I’m voting to close this question because connected speech is often misleading and causes OPs to mistate their question.

@StuartF "how wonderful a piece of complex engineering their wings are" is also a reasonable way to phrase it.

This is spoken in circumstances where the pause between "are" and "able" is not actually meant. He stops to draw breath in the middle of a phrase. If you remove the comma after "are" in your transcript it makes perfect sense, as in "you can see how things are able to do something", how meaning "in what manner" as you would expect from the dictionary definition.

Actually it isn't quite perfect. To be syntactically correct it would need to be either "how the wonderful piece of complex engineering is able to change its shape" or "how their wings are, able to change their shape". The key point is that the meaning intended is definitely "how" not "what"

But, there is "the wonderful piece of complex engineering" in "how the wonderful piece of complex engineering their wings are able to change their shape...". If removed, "how their wings are, able to change their shape" is easy to understand.

@Mr. Wang - that is correct, but you do need to remove the comma as well. That pause is not syntactic. This is a very old man lying in a boat. Being able to deliver this at all is pretty impressive.

THX, I think by saying that, he meant two things. One is to express exclamation, and the other is to express way, right?

Or

how their wings are the wonderful piece of complex engineering.
how their wings able to change their shape...


I wouldn't say he is expressing exclamation, that's not his style. He's a serious broadcaster. he wants to say "you can see how their wings are able to change shape" and at the same time indicate that their wings are a "wonderful piece of complex engineering". If this was written text he would probably have written "you can see how their wings, a wonderful piece of complex engineering, are able to change their shape and ..."

Thanks a lot!!!

The subtitles  missed a word. He says When you're close up to a flying bird like this, you can see how the wonderful piece of engineering  their wings are. The prosody of the sentence (the length and intonation of the word are) makes clear that there is indeed a full stop after "are".  I suspect there were multiple takes, and he simply got his lines wrong in that take.  He makes another grammatical error earlier (or the film editing creates it) when he's talking about the empathy the swan handler feels for them and "you can see her love and understanding of them, and they of hers".

@TimR "She has this extraordinary empathy with animals, and you can see a love and understanding of them -- and there [is the love and understanding] of hers." . I add "[is the love and understanding]". Is it proper?

@Mrwang  If you are you intentionally changing "their" to "there" in order to make a so-called "existential" declaration, then no, that is not grammatical.  BE cannot be omitted from an existential clause.   There is,  there are...   Nor can we omit the displaced subject.
